# R using data.table to cut fix time interval that contain 2 or more variables

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("2015-09-07 00:32:19", "2015-09-07 01:02:30", "2015-09-07 01:31:36", "2015-09-07 01:47:45",
"2015-09-07 02:00:17", "2015-09-07 02:07:30", "2015-09-07 03:39:41", "2015-09-07 04:04:21", "2015-09-07 04:04:21", "2015-09-07 04:04:22"), 
inOut = c("IN", "OUT", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT")) 

> df
                  time inOut
1  2015-09-07 00:32:19    IN
2  2015-09-07 01:02:30   OUT
3  2015-09-07 01:31:36    IN
4  2015-09-07 01:47:45    IN
5  2015-09-07 02:00:17    IN
6  2015-09-07 02:07:30    IN
7  2015-09-07 03:39:41    IN
8  2015-09-07 04:04:21   OUT
9  2015-09-07 04:04:21    IN
10 2015-09-07 04:04:22   OUT
>
```

I want to calculate the number of counts for IN/OUT per 15 mins,
I can do this by creating another in_df, out_df, cut these dataframe per 15 mins, and then merge this together to obtain my result. The outdf is my expected result.

```
in_df <- df[which(df$inOut== "IN"),]
out_df <- df[which(df$inOut== "OUT"),]

a <- data.frame(table(cut(as.POSIXct(in_df$time), breaks="15 mins")))
b <- data.frame(table(cut(as.POSIXct(out_df$time), breaks="15 mins")))
colnames(b) <- c("Time", "Out")
colnames(a) <- c("Time", "In")

outdf <- merge(a,b, all=TRUE)
outdf[is.na(outdf)] <- 0

> outdf
                  Time In Out
1  2015-09-07 00:32:00  1   0
2  2015-09-07 00:47:00  0   0
3  2015-09-07 01:02:00  0   1
4  2015-09-07 01:17:00  1   0
5  2015-09-07 01:32:00  0   0
6  2015-09-07 01:47:00  2   0
7  2015-09-07 02:02:00  1   0
8  2015-09-07 02:17:00  0   0
9  2015-09-07 02:32:00  0   0
10 2015-09-07 02:47:00  0   0
11 2015-09-07 03:02:00  0   0
12 2015-09-07 03:17:00  0   0
13 2015-09-07 03:32:00  1   0
14 2015-09-07 03:47:00  0   0
15 2015-09-07 04:02:00  1   2
```

My questions is how to do this with data.table to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In data.table, I would do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, timeCut := cut(as.POSIXct(time), breaks="15 mins")]

df[J(timeCut = levels(timeCut)), 
   as.list(table(inOut)), 
   on = "timeCut", 
   by = .EACHI]
```

which gives:

```
                timeCut IN OUT
 1: 2015-09-07 00:32:00  1   0
 2: 2015-09-07 00:47:00  0   0
 3: 2015-09-07 01:02:00  0   1
 4: 2015-09-07 01:17:00  1   0
 5: 2015-09-07 01:32:00  0   0
 6: 2015-09-07 01:47:00  2   0
 7: 2015-09-07 02:02:00  1   0
 8: 2015-09-07 02:17:00  0   0
 9: 2015-09-07 02:32:00  0   0
10: 2015-09-07 02:47:00  0   0
11: 2015-09-07 03:02:00  0   0
12: 2015-09-07 03:17:00  0   0
13: 2015-09-07 03:32:00  1   0
14: 2015-09-07 03:47:00  0   0
15: 2015-09-07 04:02:00  1   2
```

*Explanation* The last part is like `DT[i=J(x=my_x), j, on="x", by=.EACHI]` and can be read as:

1. Join `DT` column `x` on `my_x`.
2. Then do `j` on each subset determined by `my_x`.

In this case, `j=as.list(table(inOut))`. The table has to be coerced to a list to create multiple columns (one for each level of `inOut`).

Comment: Nice way with `.EACHI`

Comment: @Frank, thanks, your data.table sol is pretty good and clear,  I 'll marked this as answer and create another question for "dplyr"  Sol.

Comment: @JamesChen Okay, fair enough. I'd be interested to see what folks come up with for that, too. I don't know how dplyr can create multiple columns from a `table` result.

Comment: @Frank,  you can see the answer for dplyr in this link, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563243/r-using-dplyr-to-cut-fix-time-interval-that-contain-2-or-more-variables