# R using dplyr to cut fix time interval that contain 2 or more variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("2015-09-07 00:32:19", "2015-09-07 01:02:30", "2015-09-07 01:31:36", "2015-09-07 01:47:45",
"2015-09-07 02:00:17", "2015-09-07 02:07:30", "2015-09-07 03:39:41", "2015-09-07 04:04:21", "2015-09-07 04:04:21", "2015-09-07 04:04:22"), 
inOut = c("IN", "OUT", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT")) 

> df
                  time inOut
1  2015-09-07 00:32:19    IN
2  2015-09-07 01:02:30   OUT
3  2015-09-07 01:31:36    IN
4  2015-09-07 01:47:45    IN
5  2015-09-07 02:00:17    IN
6  2015-09-07 02:07:30    IN
7  2015-09-07 03:39:41    IN
8  2015-09-07 04:04:21   OUT
9  2015-09-07 04:04:21    IN
10 2015-09-07 04:04:22   OUT
>
```

I want to calculate the number of counts for IN/OUT per 15 mins, I can do this by creating another in_df, out_df, cut these dataframe per 15 mins, and then merge this together to obtain my result. The outdf is my expected result.

```
in_df <- df[which(df$inOut== "IN"),]
out_df <- df[which(df$inOut== "OUT"),]

a <- data.frame(table(cut(as.POSIXct(in_df$time), breaks="15 mins")))
b <- data.frame(table(cut(as.POSIXct(out_df$time), breaks="15 mins")))
colnames(b) <- c("Time", "Out")
colnames(a) <- c("Time", "In")

outdf <- merge(a,b, all=TRUE)
outdf[is.na(outdf)] <- 0

> outdf
                  Time In Out
1  2015-09-07 00:32:00  1   0
2  2015-09-07 00:47:00  0   0
3  2015-09-07 01:02:00  0   1
4  2015-09-07 01:17:00  1   0
5  2015-09-07 01:32:00  0   0
6  2015-09-07 01:47:00  2   0
7  2015-09-07 02:02:00  1   0
8  2015-09-07 02:17:00  0   0
9  2015-09-07 02:32:00  0   0
10 2015-09-07 02:47:00  0   0
11 2015-09-07 03:02:00  0   0
12 2015-09-07 03:17:00  0   0
13 2015-09-07 03:32:00  1   0
14 2015-09-07 03:47:00  0   0
15 2015-09-07 04:02:00  1   2
```

I have asked similar questions on this link [R using data.table to cut fix time interval that contain 2 or more variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558568/r-using-data-table-to-cut-fix-time-interval-that-contain-2-or-more-variables)  and Frank have provide good sol for data.table, and I wonder if someone have sol for dplyr? And if it have similar powerful command just like Frank data.table sol ==>  df[J(levels(timeCut)), as.list(table(inOut)), by=.EACHI]

And for dplyr, I have try below, but it seem below will missing 0 value(ie, 2015-09-07 00:47:00 0 0), also I want to mutate a IN and OUT count that same as my expect result(outdf), please comment, Thanks.

```
as.data.frame(df  %>% group_by(inOut, timeCut= cut(as.POSIXct(time), breaks="15 min"))   %>% summarise(n()))
  inOut             timeCut n()
1    IN 2015-09-07 00:32:00   1
2    IN 2015-09-07 01:17:00   1
3    IN 2015-09-07 01:47:00   2
4    IN 2015-09-07 02:02:00   1
5    IN 2015-09-07 03:32:00   1
6    IN 2015-09-07 04:02:00   1
7   OUT 2015-09-07 01:02:00   1
8   OUT 2015-09-07 04:02:00   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using `dplyr` and `reshape2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

my_levels <-
  data_frame(timeCut = levels(cut(as.POSIXct(df$time), breaks="15 min")))

my_df <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(timeCut = cut(as.POSIXct(time), breaks = "15 min")) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(as.character)) %>% 
  right_join(., my_levels) %>% 
  select(-time) %>% 
  dcast(timeCut ~ inOut, length)
```

#### Result

```
               timeCut IN OUT NA
1  2015-09-07 00:32:00  1   0  0
2  2015-09-07 00:47:00  0   0  1
3  2015-09-07 01:02:00  0   1  0
4  2015-09-07 01:17:00  1   0  0
5  2015-09-07 01:32:00  0   0  1
6  2015-09-07 01:47:00  2   0  0
7  2015-09-07 02:02:00  1   0  0
8  2015-09-07 02:17:00  0   0  1
9  2015-09-07 02:32:00  0   0  1
10 2015-09-07 02:47:00  0   0  1
11 2015-09-07 03:02:00  0   0  1
12 2015-09-07 03:17:00  0   0  1
13 2015-09-07 03:32:00  1   0  0
14 2015-09-07 03:47:00  0   0  1
15 2015-09-07 04:02:00  1   2  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr+ reshape2 sol

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("2015-09-07 00:32:19", "2015-09-07 01:02:30", "2015-09-07 01:31:36", "2015-09-07 01:47:45",
                          "2015-09-07 02:00:17", "2015-09-07 02:07:30", "2015-09-07 03:39:41", "2015-09-07 04:04:21", "2015-09-07 04:04:21", "2015-09-07 04:04:22"), 
                 inOut = c("IN", "OUT", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT")) 


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>% 
  group_by(inOut) %>%
  do(data.frame(table(cut(as.POSIXct(.$time), breaks="15 mins")))) %>%
  group_by(inOut, Var1) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(Freq)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(inOut,value, fill=0)


# Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
# 
#                    Var1    IN   OUT
#                   (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  2015-09-07 00:32:00     1     0
# 2  2015-09-07 00:47:00     0     0
# 3  2015-09-07 01:02:00     0     1
# 4  2015-09-07 01:17:00     1     0
# 5  2015-09-07 01:32:00     0     0
# 6  2015-09-07 01:47:00     2     0
# 7  2015-09-07 02:02:00     1     0
# 8  2015-09-07 02:17:00     0     0
# 9  2015-09-07 02:32:00     0     0
# 10 2015-09-07 02:47:00     0     0
# 11 2015-09-07 03:02:00     0     0
# 12 2015-09-07 03:17:00     0     0
# 13 2015-09-07 03:32:00     1     0
# 14 2015-09-07 03:47:00     0     0
# 15 2015-09-07 04:02:00     1     2
```

You will see a warning that you can ignore, or just use `stringsAsFactors = F` when you create your example dataset.
You can also rename columns at some point in the process and replace `Var1` with something more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr + tidyr sol

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the table to achieve the desired format

```
library(reshape2)


df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(inOut, 
             timeCut= cut(as.POSIXct(time), breaks="15 min")) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    dcast(timeCut ~ inOut, value.var = "n")
```

Add all intervals

```
intervals <- data.frame(timeCut = levels(cut(as.POSIXct(df$time), 
                                             breaks="15 mins")))
df3 <- df2 %>%
    mutate(timeCut = as.character(timeCut)) %>%
    merge(intervals, all = TRUE)
```

Replace NA values by 0 if needed

```
df3[is.na(df3)]  <- 0

> df3
               timeCut IN OUT
1  2015-09-07 00:32:00  1   0
2  2015-09-07 00:47:00  0   0
3  2015-09-07 01:02:00  0   1
4  2015-09-07 01:17:00  1   0
5  2015-09-07 01:32:00  0   0
6  2015-09-07 01:47:00  2   0
7  2015-09-07 02:02:00  1   0
8  2015-09-07 02:17:00  0   0
9  2015-09-07 02:32:00  0   0
10 2015-09-07 02:47:00  0   0
11 2015-09-07 03:02:00  0   0
12 2015-09-07 03:17:00  0   0
13 2015-09-07 03:32:00  1   0
14 2015-09-07 03:47:00  0   0
15 2015-09-07 04:02:00  1   2
```

The `reshape2::dcast` function has now been replaced by `tidyr::spread`, but I haven't gotten used to it yet. See the [data wrangling cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) for more details on data preparation.

Comment: Your solution is missing intervals.

Comment: Thanks Paul4forest, but As per Miha, this sol missing the ( 2015-09-07 00:47:00  0   0 ),  anyway, I am clear enough now with Antoniosk,  Miha sol and your hints.